# Are environment variables associative?

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, environment

In windows 7, if you do something like this in the command line:

```
X=Debug

Y=ABC\%X%
```

then...

```
X=Release

Y=?
```

Comment: Why not just type it yourself and see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows this:

```
set X=Debug
set Y=ABC\%X%
X=Release
echo %Y%
```

Prints:

```
ABC\DEBUG'
```

Here's what happens, step by step:

```
set X=Debug
```

Environment variable `X` is set to the value 'Debug'

```
set Y=ABC\%X%
```

Variable expansion converts the command to:

```
set Y=ABC\Debug
```

And this command is executed. No association is retained between `X` and `Y`.

```
set X=Release
```

Has no effect on `Y`

```
echo %Y%
```

Displays:

```
ABC\Debug
```

Comment: +1 I completely misread the question, I should read more carefully next time :)

Comment: would be cool if they had a way to make them associative, will save a some effort

Comment: @SeeknInspYre: Try looking up "setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion", it might be what you're after.

Comment: @user786653, I don't think that will help. It just improves the expansion rules so grouped statements can use e-vars normally, etc.

Comment: @SeeknInspYre, you just have to repeat `set Y=ABC\%X%` where needed.